# How to use Google’s postmessage redirect uri scheme?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-signin, google-oauth

Some Google site like [api exploer](https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://monorail-prod.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/monorail/v1/) use a [mixed scheme](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/03/postmessage-oauth-20.html) instead of redirecting to an uri where a postmessage event is triggered by a callback function from the opener window which is received by the opener window *(so `window.location.origin` is different from `window.origin` but I don’t understand how)*.

I couldn’t find documentation about it, but maybe I searched incorrectly.
The main advantage seems there’s no need for server side token registering as everything happens through JavaScript.

```html
Here’s <a href='javascript:window.open("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com&immediate=false&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&include_granted_scopes=false&proxy=oauth2relay604084667&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=https://apis-explorer.appspot.com&response_type=token&gsiwebsdk=1&state=657454173|0.195379257&authuser=0&jsh=m;/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k");'>an example script link</a> that will trigger a Domexception if not opened from https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/
```

Additionally, http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth access `window.opener` child’s elements if `window.opener.origin` match the origin parameter 
 given in the url and thus bypassing sop *(but I don’t understand how since no Acess-control-Allow-* headers are used)*. Otherwise an exception is triggered.

So what is the JavaScript api for performing oauth2 authentification with postmessage ? what is the purpose of the `proxy=` url parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. You can use the [Google sign-in api](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) for javascript to request extra scopes. See the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference)
2. You can use [OAuth2 for javascript](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)

Comment: nice but I knew it. How to use those apis for authenticating without server restrictions.

Comment: Might be easier if you explain what you are trying to do. What is the server restrictions you are running into?

Comment: I am trying to understant how this meachanism works. So I need to reproduce it because studying the api explorer is no longer enough.

Comment: This may help.  http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-specs-ab/Week-of-Mon-20151116/005865.html

Comment: but isn't the way I am describing restfull instead of rpc based.